# The solutions of $y'' = 2$ don't form a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> "The solutions of $y'' = 2$ don't form a subspace - the right side $b=2$
> is not zero."

This is a quote on page 172 of Intro to Linear Algebra by Strang. What does this mean? Can someone explain how a differential equation relates to the idea of subspaces, and then why this statement is correct (e.g. what characteristics of subspaces does $y''=2$ violate).

Comment: It is straightforward from linear algebra that the solutions to an ODE which is also homogeneous have a vector space structure. And as fellow mates showed below, if the equation is not homogeneous the result does not hold.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$y=x^2$ and $y=x^2+1$ are solutions of $y''=2$, but their sum is not.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: more general fact -- the solutions of $y''=\phi(t)$ do not form a subspace unless if $\phi(t)=0$.

Consider $f(t)=t^2$ and $g(t)=t^2$. Then both $f$ and $g$ solve the differential equation $y''=2$, yet their sum does not. Thus, the set of solutions to $y''=2$ cannot be a subspace as it is not closed under addition.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if

$y_1'' = 2, \tag 1$

and

$y_2'' = 2, \tag 2$

then

$(y_1 + y_2)'' = y_1'' + y_2'' = 2 + 2 = 4 \ne 2; \tag 3$

thus the set of solutions with

$y'' = 2 \tag 4$

is not closed under addition, hence cannot be a subspace.

This result of course generalizes in accord with the suggestions of ilovebulbasaur in his/her answer, insofar as taking, for any non-vanishing function $\phi$,

$y_1'' = y_2'' = \phi \ne 0 \tag 5$

yields

$(y_1 + y_2)'' = y_1'' + y_2'' = \phi + \phi = 2\phi \ne \phi, \tag 6$

showing the set of solutions for which (5) binds is not a subspace.